# Call a function of an extension / addon

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, screenshot

Can I run a function of an extension from javascript?

I installed an extension to capture screens and wondered if it was possible to call the function Capture the entire screen from my own html file using javascript.

I have tried many libraries (html2canvas, webkit, etc.) and none were useful and that is why I  wonder if I can use the power and simplicity of a chrome extension.

If it is not possible with Chrome, Firefox has that capability on their addons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Look at the [Chrome extensions documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication)

Comment: It's great to heard that! Thanks for the reply anfilat.